# Waiting for text in a textarea to change

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a `textarea` defined as `<textarea id="EmailMessage">`.

The `textarea` has some sort of generic text in it before you select other parameters in the page.

When you change this box's value to "External", the text in the email box becomes more specific:

[image]

Then the text looks something like this:

[image]

in the email box.  I want to read this but I noticed that if I read it too soon it will still have the old text.  I read the text by finding the element and then getting the value like:

```
String txt = ele.getAttribute("value").
```

So I want to wait until "SubAccount" appears in the box so I used an xpath:

```
//textarea[@id='EmailMessage' and contains(@value, 'SubAccount')]
```

but it times out waiting for that element.  Also in chrome inspect if I do a search for that element

```
//textarea [@id='EmailMessage' and contains(@value,'SubAccount')]
```

it is also not found.

Is there a reason for this? How would I search?

In case it matters I am using Eclipse (Mars) and Java and Chrome.

Comment: sorry, but i am finding it hard to understand your usecase.

Comment: try String txt = ele.gettext() and then verify using txt.contains("SubAccount")

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the textarea directly with 'id'. If not, then check if textarea is inside an iframe.

Use `ExpectedConditions - textToBePresentInElementValue(elem, text)` to wait for the desired text to be visible. Or you can use the `attributeContains(elem, value, text)` to wait for the new text to appear. [Expected Condition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html)

Comment: like so: wait.until(
      ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(By.xpath(issueActionEmailMessage), emailWait));

Comment: emailWait is the text

Comment: Yeah... The first one requires an exact text. The second option may suit your needs better as it will look for only a portion of the text.